# How to add a custom button on contact's to open with my app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

Well, I wanna know if it possible open a contact with a cordova app from "contacts" app like WhatsApp.

See here a example:

[image: Example of WhatsApp]

I search on Google and npm, but nothing...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's really good documentation about this on Android's website here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider

Make sure you read the entire post, but specifically check out this section that talks about adding your stuff into the `Contact`'s screen:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#SocialStreamInteraction

Also, if you haven't yet, you might want to create your own `Account` and `SyncProvider`, check out these tutorials:
http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/
and
http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should probably investigate using a plugin to display Contacts, see:

https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=contacts